# getServerSideProps not working returning undefined when mapping next js

Tags: next.js

what am i doing wrong here? i am trying to do getServerSideProps but
localhost is working fine when hosted  i get
Internal Server Error 500

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import Navigation from "./navigation";
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
// import MyEditor from "./editor";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import { useState } from "react";
import Questions3 from "../pages/question";

import axios from "axios";
import { FormControl, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

import InputGroup from "react-bootstrap/InputGroup";
function Home({ data }) {
  const [Questions, setQuestions] = useState();
  const [deatils1, setdeatils] = useState();

  function clickQuestion() {
    axios
      .post("https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/questionpost", {
        Name: Questions,

        Summary: deatils1,

        // username: this.props.sign.displayName,
        // useremail: this.props.sign.email,
      })
      .then(() => {
        window.location.reload();
      });
  }
  function question(e) {
    setQuestions(e.target.value);
    // this.setState({ ask: e.target.value });
  }
  function deatils(e) {
    setdeatils(e.target.value);
    // this.setState({ ask: e.target.value });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>wixten </title>
        <meta
          name="google-site-verification"
          content="rqVH7Jc-L-NyyCYGf2LOEjRPFEUvi8iImncslSfxtac"
        />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/wixten.png" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="have all ur doubts cleared here at wixten . At wixten ask any thing you want and anyone in the world can see your questin and will be able to answer it "
        />
      </Head>
      <Navigation />
      <div>
        <div className="container search-box">
          <Form>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="exampleForm.ControlInput1">
              <Form.Label>Title</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                onChange={question}
                placeholder="ask anything?"
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group
              className="mb-3"
              controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1"
            >
              <Form.Label>question</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control onChange={deatils} as="textarea" rows={3} />
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>

          {/* <Form>
            <InputGroup
              className="mb-3"
              // onChange={this.question}
              // value={ask}
              // value={this.state.ask}
            >
              <FormControl
                placeholder="ask anything?"
                aria-label="ask anything?"
                // aria-label="ask anything?"
                aria-describedby="basic-addon2"
              />
              <FormControl as="textarea" rows={3} />
            </InputGroup>
          </Form> */}
          <Button
            type="submit"
            disabled={!deatils1 || !Questions}
            onClick={clickQuestion}
            variant="outline-secondary"
            id="button-addon2"
          >
            ask?
          </Button>

          <Questions3 data={data} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const res = await fetch(`https://ask-over.herokuapp.com/questapi`);
  const data = await res.json();
  // console.log(data);
  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { props: { data } };
}
export default Home;
```

pages/question/index.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Alert from "react-bootstrap/Alert";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import Head from "next/head";
function Question3(props) {
  const data = props.data;


  return (
    <div className="question11">
     
      {data.map((itm) => (
       
        <Link
          key={itm._id}
          href={{
            pathname: "query/[itm]",
        
          }}
          as={`query/${encodeURIComponent(itm._id)}`}
        >
         
          <Alert className="question13">{itm.Name}</Alert>
        </Link>
     
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}


export default Question3;
```

when i call http://localhost:3000/the question page is rendering

after deploying to vercel i get the following error

when i depolyed i get this error
[image]

Comment: `getServerSideProps` has to be exported from the page. Simply importing `./pages/question` won't work. Declare `getServerSideProps` with the desired logic in your `index.js` page, so that page can receive the props from it.

Comment: i think the bug is somewhere else. You should share full code. if something does not build in prod, should not be compiled in dev netiher, i hope next.js fixes this

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's a non-page component. You can't use `getServerSideProps` in non-page components.

Try calling the API from your page file and pass it down as props. You could also create a context.

> getServerSideProps can only be exported from a page. You can’t export it from non-page files.

[Source](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)

Comment: will it work if it is the index.js  page?

Comment: Yes, now you updated your question it is clearer. `getServerSideProps` will work if you put it in index.js :) you could also move your Questions3 component to the /components folder, because Nextjs uses file-based routing and your component in /pages/questions/index.jsx is resulting in a route at /questions which I'm not sure if you intended or not.

Comment: i tryed puting it in index.js still not wroking

Comment: don't work. I've tried put it in index.js. same, still not working